# How to write in shorthand multiple if else in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I need to assign a value to an variable in coffeescript. How to write this code in short form:

```
if obj and obj.event and obj.event.name
  variable = obj.event.name
else 
  variable = ''
```

Comment: Consider using property soaking: `variable = if obj?.event?.name? then obj.event.name else ''`

Comment: Oh, really, I can write something life Swift.